# Why I cannot use Convert() column in a where clause?

Tags: sql

The following SQL

```
select creationdate as dt 
from dbo.Posts2
where dt > '2013-06-31'
```

gives error when running:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'dt'.

### Update

this works:

```
Declare @date as varchar(30)
set @date='2008-07-31 21:42:52.667'
select convert(datetime,@date, 101) as [DateColumn]
```

but this failed:

```
select creationdate from dbo.Posts2
where  convert(datetime, creationdate, 101) > '2013-06-31'
```

The error is:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted
>   in an out-of-range value.

Why??

Comment: See "Logical Processing Order of the [`SELECT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx) statement": "because the `SELECT` clause is step 8, any column aliases or derived columns defined in that clause cannot be referenced by preceding clauses." `WHERE` is step 4.

Comment: Ohh, nice explanation. I'm going to read this processing order right now.

Comment: Does `SELECT CAST(creationdate AS DATE) FROM Posts2` work?  You can view non-date values with `SELECT creationdate FROM Posts2 WHERE ISDATE(creationdate) = 0`

Comment: I tried, there's no non-date values. and the cast failed with "*Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.*"

Comment: @smwikipedia perhaps some sample data?  What database/version are you using?

Comment: @GoatCO the creationdate contains value like '2008-07-31 21:42:52.667', I am using SQL server 2012 (11.0.3128.0).

Comment: `SELECT creationdate FROM Posts2 WHERE TRY_CONVERT(DATE,creationdate) IS NULL`  is handy in 2012, but as mentioned, June only has 30 days, so it's your `WHERE` criteria that has the faulty date.

Answer (score 4):

You **can't** use aliases in the `where` clause.

Just write

```
where convert(datetime, creationdate) > '2013-06-31'
```

Edit about the datetime/varchar conversion error:

You are trying to compare to a date that doesn't exist: June only has 30 days, so '2013-06-31' is not a date for SQL Server.

Comment: More precisely, you can't use *column* aliases defined in the `SELECT` clause in the `WHERE` clause. There are other types of aliases, and you definitely can use e.g. table/rowset aliases in the `WHERE` clause, or column aliases introduced as part of a table alias.

Comment: this convert() in the where clause results in an error "*The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.*", while in the select clause, it works.

Comment: my creationdate looks like this "2008-07-31 21:42:52.667"

Comment: I believe it means that your SQL Server believes that'2013-06-31' is a varchar. Maybe it expects american date formats? Or maybe since you're comparing with datetime instead of date, you should use something like '2013-06-31 00:00:00.001'? Date issues are always tricky...